# Exists a way to create customization layers upon the prestashop?

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

I'm beginning a project using the prestashop. I need use the prestashop like a core and I need to make customization layers upon the core.

I think this is a better way to update the prestashop in future without to lost my customizations.

Someone have an idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of customization do you want to make ?
Actualy, the best way to customize your prestashop without loosing your changes in future versions is just to use one of these three options :

1. [Writing a theme (use the default theme and buid on it!)](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Theme+development+fundamentals)
2. Writing modules
3. [Override core files using the *Override* mecanism](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors)

I think the *Override* mecanism might be what you are looking for, it kind of act as a "layer" on the core...

Hope that helps

Comment: I want to remove fields and include others in edits pages. For example: tax fields don't are necessary to me, so, I would like to remove.

Comment: then I think you might need to : 1/ create a [back-office theme](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Characteristics+of+a+back-office+theme) and 2/use overrides to modify the controllers